# BibTeX error LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using TexPad as editor and I do the latex, bibtex, latex, latex compilation. The weird thing is that I have two citations that show up and two that come as question marks, I am really puzzled about what the problem is and would appreciate help very much.

This is my tex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{plain}
\begin{document}

xx\cite{Yu}
\cite{doiX}
\cite{labinger}
\cite{ab}
\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

and my .bib file:

```
@article{doiX,
   author = "He Hao and Ling-Yan Chen and Wai-Yeung  Wong and 
             Wing-Hong  Chan and Albert W. M.  Lee",
   title  = "Practical Synthetic Approach to Chiral Sulfonimides (CSIs) 
             Brnsted Acids for Organocatalysis",
} 

@book{Yu,
   series = {Topics in current chemistry},
   volume = {292},
   publisher = {Springer},
   isbn = {978-3-642-12355-9},
   year = {2010},
   title = {C-H Activation},
   language = {eng},
   address = {Heidelberg},
   author = {Yu, Jin-Quan and Ackermann, xL},
   keywords = {ORGANISCHE SYNTHESE (CHEMIE): 547.057{,
}

@article{labinger,
   title  = {Understanding and exploiting C-H bond activation},
   author = {hallo},
   journal= {Nature},
   volume = {417},
   number = {6888},
   pages  = {507},
   year   = {2002},
   publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}

@article{ab,
   author = "He Haond Ling-Yan Chen and Wai-Yeung  Wong and  
             Wing-Hong  Chan and Albert W. M.  Lee",
   title  = "Practical Synthetic Approach to Chiral Sulfonimides 
             (CSIs)  Brnsted Acids for Organocatalysis",
}
```

and this is what the output looks like:

[image]

The error in the log says:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `ab' on page 1 undefined on input line 8.

(./BiBTexTest.bbl) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap
/pdftex.map}] (./BiBTexTest.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You have to run an extra program called BibTeX. Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number

Comment: Incidentally, why do you load the `plain` package? AFAICT, it's meant to be used for users who wish to enter plain-TeX commands in LaTeX document. Is that the case in your document?

Answer (score 2):

When you ran BibTeX on the above bibliographic entries, you must have gotten a fatal-error message about the entry with key `Yu`, because that entry contains the following faulty `keywords` field:

```
keywords = {ORGANISCHE SYNTHESE (CHEMIE): 547.057{,
```

The second instance of `{` must surely be `}`. Once you make the called-for correction, the four entries can be compiled.

By the way, "can be compiled" does *not* imply that the *contents* of the bibliographic entries are correct. For instance, the entries with keys `ab` and `doiX` are missing the required `journal` and `year` fields. Moreover, the `ab` entry has the following, rather dubious, `author` field:

```
author = "He Haond Ling-Yan Chen and Wai-Yeung Wong ..."
```

This must surely be

```
author = "He, Hao and Ling-Yan Chen and Wai-Yeung Wong ..."
```

With Chinese names, be extra careful to identify what are the first or given name components and what are the last or family name components.

Next, `Brnsted` is incorrect; please change both instances of `Brnsted` to `Br{\o}nsted`. Incidentally, the author "hallo" [!!] in the `labinger` entry has got to be wrong.

And, I doubt that the `Ackermann` item in the `author` field of the `Yu` entry is correct. I think you should replace

```
author = {Yu, Jin-Quan and Ackermann, xL},
```

with

```
editor = {Yu, Jin-Quan and Shi, Zhangjie},
```

That book contains 12 chapters authored by various contributors. (One of the chapters, in fact, was co-authored by L. Ackermann and R. Vicente!) Are you really citing the entire book? Or did you mean to cite a specific chapter from that book? If so, you should be using an entry of type `@incollection`, so that you can provide information about the authors, the title of the chapter, and possibly the number of the chapter and the page range in addition to the `editor` and `booktitle` fields.

Finally, don't forget to encase certain uppercase-letter strings, such as `CSIs`, `C-H` and (yes!) `Br{\o}nsted`, in curly braces so that BibTeX doesn't convert them to all-lowercase.